# Meaning of the `from` parameter of `lua_resume`

Tags: c, lua

From [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_resume):

> ```
> int lua_resume (lua_State *L, lua_State *from, int nargs);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The parameter `from` represents the coroutine that is resuming `L`. If there is no such coroutine, this parameter can be `NULL`.

But it does not say much to me. What exactly does it do? In what circumstances I *must* pass anything other than NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by nothing other than the [source code](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ldo.c.html#lua_resume) for 5.2 it would appear that `from` is only used to correctly count the number of nested C calls during the resume.

```
L->nCcalls = (from) ? from->nCcalls + 1 : 1;
```

and

```
lua_assert(L->nCcalls == ((from) ? from->nCcalls : 0));
```

The implementation of [`coroutine.resume`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lcorolib.c.html#auxresume) seems to use it that way.

It resumes the coroutine on the coroutine thread with a `from` value of the main thread that is resuming it.

```
status = lua_resume(co, L, narg);
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.   There's a lot going on in that function, and the behavior seems subtle.   And I'm still not sure when/why to set the second argument NULL or non-NULL after reading the answer here.

Comment: @BadZen: The `L->nCcalls` field (and the corresponding limit `LUAI_MAXCCALLS`) is there to prevent you from blowing the C stack if you accidentally call a `lua_CFunction` recursively. However since the `nCcalls` field is stored in the `lua_State`, you could fool this check by allocating and resuming a new coroutine somewhere in the recursive call chain. Copying the count from the calling coroutine fixes that problem.